# Generic return types and lambda function arguments

Tags: java, generics, lambda

I'm currently working on abstract code that can handle operations on any grid-like structure.  In lieu of concrete methods, I've been trying to develop a framework that accepts lambda expressions and provides functionality based on directional relationships between grid elements, and I've run into trouble when attempting to return a generic type into these methods.

I have a working methods like the one below, that accept a lambda Function that finds the grid element in a particular direction and a Consumer that executes some method on each of the elements.

```
public static <E> void forEachClockwise(Direction d, Function<Direction, ? extends E> f, Consumer<? super E> c){
    /*For each of the orthogonal directions, in order:*/
        c.accept(f.apply(d));
    /*end For*/

}
```

Instead of having to pass an element-finding Function every time this method is called, I decided it would be good to have an interface 'Orthogonal' that has such a function declared, and overload the forEachClockwise method to accept elements of this interface.

```
public static <O extends Orthogonal> void forEachClockwise(Direction d, O center, Consumer<O> c){
    forEachClockwise(d, center::findNextByDirection, c);
}
```

I used generics here and declared  so that the Consumer method would be able to access fields of the grid elements without casting.  I'm concerned this was a poor design choice, as the Orthogonal interface and the test class I created haven't compiled without warnings and without casts, despite trying a few different things.

```
public interface Orthogonal {
    public <E extends Orthogonal> E findNextByDirection(Direction a);
}
```

The two 'valid' implementations of findNextByDirection I've tried are:

```
/* in Coordinate implements Orthogonal: */
@Override
public <E extends Orthogonal> E findNextByDirection(Direction a) {
    return (E) (/*The proper Coordinate*/);
}
```

And

```
@Override
public Coordinate findNextByDirection(Direction a) {
    return /*The proper Coordinate*/;
}
//Warning on return type declaration:
/*Type safety: The return type Element for findNextByDirection(Direction) from the type Element needs unchecked conversion to conform to E from the type Orthogonal*/
```

Optimally, I would like to have a method that the forEachClockwise (and other methods) can accept, which returns an element of the same class that calls it, without casting.  Coordinate's findNextByDirection should return a Coordinate, Address should return an Address, Cell should return Cell, etc.  Other questions and answers I've looked at discuss how to get away with making a method with a generic return type, but I haven't found any hints on how to use this kind of method as a lambda parameter.

A couple things I haven't yet tried are making a new findByDirection method that accepts some kind of Orthogonal and a Direction as arguments, or calling the forEachClockwise method with some method defined in Orthogonal, though those approaches sound about as reasonable as what I've attempted.  The other approach I've seen that works is to give the interface its own generic type, but it feels distinctly wrong and purpose-defeating to declare every Orthogonal class as "MyClass implements Orthogonal"

Have I been designing this interface entirely wrong from the beginning, and expecting generics to do something they weren't designed for?  Or is there a simpler way of getting a class to call the right method and return elements of its own type generically?

Full code:

```
package test;

import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Function;


public enum Direction {
    NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST;

    public static <O extends Orthogonal> void forEachClockwise(Direction d, O center, Consumer<O> c){
        forEachClockwise(d, center::findNextByDirection, c);
    }

    public static <X> void forEachClockwise(Direction d, Function<Direction, ? extends X> f, Consumer<? super X> c){
        c.accept(f.apply(d));
        forEachExcept(d, f, c);
    }

    public static <X> void forEachExcept(Direction d, Function<Direction, ? extends X> f, Consumer<? super X> c){
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            d = Direction.getClockwise(d);
            c.accept(f.apply(d));
        }
    }

    public static Direction getClockwise(Direction d){
        switch(d){
        case EAST:
            return SOUTH;
        case NORTH:
            return EAST;
        case SOUTH:
            return WEST;
        case WEST:
            return NORTH;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

}

interface Orthogonal {
    public <E extends Orthogonal> E findNextByDirection(Direction a);
}






class Coordinate implements Orthogonal{

    int x;
    int y;

    public Coordinate(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }


    @Override //Warning on "Coordinate" below.  Compiler suggests writing
              //entire <E extends Orthogonal> method signature
    public Coordinate findNextByDirection(Direction a) {
        switch(a){
            case NORTH:
                return new Coordinate(x+1, y);
            case SOUTH:
                return new Coordinate(x-1, y);
            case EAST:
                return new Coordinate(x, y+1);
            case WEST:
                return new Coordinate(x, y-1);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you could produce a full example that compiles (with warnings). For example, this implementation of Orthogonal compiles without warning: `public class Element implements Orthogonal {
    @Override public Element findNextByDirection(Direction a) {
      return this;
    }
  }`

Comment: That snippet does compile with a warning for me, on the return type declaration Element:

"Type safety: The return type Element for findNextByDirection(Direction) from the type Element needs unchecked conversion to conform to E from the type Orthagonal"

Comment: did you copy the method signature (returning an Element, not an Orthogonal)?

Comment: Yes.  I'm using Eclipse to compile.  Judging from other questions, using Eclipse vs. javac can throw different compiler warnings and errors when using passing generics.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume for a moment there are two classes implementing `Orthogonal` - `Coordinate` and `Area`.

```
public <E extends Orthogonal> E findNextByDirection(Direction a);
```

What you declared here is a templated method. The declaration basically says: "given a particular context, this method will always return the expected type - if the result is to be assigned to a `Coordinate` variable, the method will return a `Coordinate`, if to an `Area` - it will return an `Area` and so on - as long as what is expected is a type that implements `Orthogonal`"

However, when you try to implement it in `Coordinate` as `public Coordinate findNextByDirection(Direction a)`, you no longer promise to return whatever is expected in a given context - you now only ever return `Coordinate`, thus breaking the contract declared in the interface. Worse still, if you think of it, there was no way of actually satisfying that contract in the first place.

What you should do is declare your interface generic (`Orthogonal<E>`) and drop the `<E extends Orthogonal>` from the method declaration.

If it is the declaration `class Coordinate implements Orthogonal<Coordinate>` that feels "distinctly wrong", it shouldn't. This is common practice, used extensively in the SDK itself (see `Comparable` for instance).

If you find it necessary for `findNextByDirection` to return an `Orthogonal`, you can declare the return type as `Orthogonal<E>`. You should even be able to implement your method in `Coordinate` as `public Coordinate findNextByDirection(Direction a)` without any warnings due to Java's type covariance.

Comment: "Worse still, if you think of it, there was no way of actually satisfying that contract in the first place." Unless it always returned `null` :)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that from your `findNextByDirection` method, you need to return the same type as the enclosing class. So in your Coordinate example, you need to return a Coordinate.

If that's the case, you can go one step further with the generics:

```
interface Orthogonal<E extends Orthogonal<E>> {
    public E findNextByDirection(Direction a);
}
class Coordinate implements Orthogonal<Coordinate> {
  //rest is the same
  //you should not have any warnings left
}

public static <O extends Orthogonal<O>> void forEachClockwise2(Direction d, O center, Consumer<O> c){
    forEachClockwise(d, center::findNextByDirection, c);
}
```

Note: the two `forEachClockwise` methods have a conflict (same raw signature) so I have renamed one of them to `forEachClockwise2`.